# Multithreading not working simultaneously in c# windows form

Tags: c#, multithreading

i am trying to use multithreading to complete my task in less time. But when i run my thread it execute one by one not work simultaneously. if i use Thread.Sleep() my interface hanged until the all threads process completed. Here is my code.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            dataGridView.Columns.Add("Google", "Google"); // 
            dataGridView.Columns.Add("Google1", "Google1");
            dataGridView.Rows.Add("google.com", "");
            dataGridView.Rows.Add("amazon.com", "");
            dataGridView.Rows.Add("flipkart.com", "");
            dataGridView.Rows.Add("snapdeal.com", "");
            dataGridView.Rows.Add("gmail.com", "");

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Google", "Google");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Google1", "Google1");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("google.com", "");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("amazon.com", "");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("flipkart.com", "");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("snapdeal.com", "");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("gmail.com", ""
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Thread x = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thread1));
            x.Start();
            Thread x1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thread2));
            x1.Start();
}

public void thread1()
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {

                foreach (DataGridViewRow x in lstview.Rows)
                {
                    if (x.Cells["Google"].Value == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (x.Cells["Google1"].Value == "")
                    {
                        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                        x.Cells["Google1"].Value = "Thread1";
                        webBrowser1.Navigate(x.Cells["Google"].Value.ToString());


                        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                        {
                            Application.DoEvents();
                        }

                    }
                    // Task.WaitAll();
                }
            }));
}

        public void thread2()
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {

                foreach (DataGridViewRow x in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (x.Cells["Google"].Value == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (x.Cells["Google1"].Value == "")
                    {
                        webBrowser2.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                        x.Cells["Google1"].Value = "thread2";
                        webBrowser2.Navigate(x.Cells["Google"].Value.ToString());


                        while (webBrowser2.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                        {
                            Application.DoEvents();
                        }

                    }

                 }
            }));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new thread which calls `Invoke` method.

Look at the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) for this method:

> Executes a delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying
>   window handle.

So that delegate will be still executed on `UI` thread anyway, because `Form` control that you are using belongs to `UI` thread.

If you remove call to `Invoke` - exception will be thrown because you cannot access UI elements from non "UI" thread.

If you want to speed up things, learn about `async/await` or at least about `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

The UI elements (like your DataGrid) can only be accessed by the UI thread. WinForms and WPF/Silverlight doesn't allow access to controls from multiple threads.

In your case your try to invoke code in main thread, thats why it works syncronizly.

Sory but there is no way to do process your method asyncronizly. Because all your attempts to access UI elements whill return an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I believe, with your code is accessing UI elements in your thread. Threads are suitable for cases where you're doing a certain task not related to UI may be like invoking a service to fetch the data and later bind it to UI element. When you have code sitting in Thread is accessing the UI element it will end up being sequential because UI elements can only be accessed on the thread they've been created in and in this case it will be UI thread.

Effectively, both the threads in your case are accessing the UI element and hence give an impression sequential rather parallel.

Essentially you will have to refactor your code to make it UI independent and achieve your goal.